# VS Typescript cannot find local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I currently have little more than the shell of a Typescript & nodejs project repo in Visual Studio, and I can't figure out an import error. I have a top-level file, application.ts, that is erroring when trying to import a local folder, source, which has an index.ts file. My directory structure looks like this:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
application.ts
source
    index.ts
```

And, the error in appliation.js is `Cannot find module './source'.`

[image]

[image]

For the record, I also tried `import { } from 'source'`, dropping the `./` but that also did not work. Am I missing something really obvious here?

EDIT: Adding contents of tsconfig.json and package.json for relevancy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I was under the impression that folders can be imported in this fashion if they have an index.ts file. If there is another way to import a folder, please share.

Comment: Thats correct @AnthonyMonterrosa, what happens if you add the named export you are tying to  import in between those brackets?

Comment: @MartinWahlberg it says `(TS) '<name>' is declared but never read.'` Intellisense doesn't see the definition it seems, because the tooltip doesn't show the type (like it usually does).

Comment: @roko that doesn't make much sense given that every module on npm does exactly this.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa I think this sounds like your TS-server is struggeling, have you tried restarting it?

Comment: Does actually compiling it work? Or does that fail too?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I belive you may be missing out on some best practices

Comment: @MartinWahlberg I googled how to restart TS-server in VS, but I couldn't find it. Mind sharing how to do that?

Comment: @JonasWilms the compilation fails, and the failure mentions the error above `(TS) Cannot find module './source'`.

Comment: command + shift + p on mac and type in restart ts server. If you´re on windows i guess it´s the same but with ctrl

Comment: @roko I think you have a slight missunderstanding: importing from a folder (at least that's what most bundlers do) imports from the index(.js|.ts) file in that folder. It's quite a common practice to reexport stuff from other files there.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa Whats in you´re tsconfig?

Comment: @MartinWahlberg I wasn't able to find it, and ctrl + shift + p did not do anything for me in Visual Studio (not VS Code, to be clear). As for tsconfig, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @JonasWilms I discourage always importing wildcards from a folder. Say `import * as Methods from ./blah` 1.of: `*` !== `{ }` and 2. what's `Methods`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @roko yes, wildcard imports are generally a bad idea ... bu the op doesn't use one?

Comment: @JonasWilms Seems I guessed right OP's intentions with an empty `{ }` than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you add  `"include": ["./**/*"]` to your tsconfig.json it will solve the problem

Make it look something like this:

Keep what you have in compilerOptions and exclude but add include in between like this

```
"compilerOptions":{},
"include":["./**/*"],
"exclude":[]
```

Comment: This worked! Turns out having `"target": "ESNext"` or `"module": "ESNext"` caused the error. I guess I misunderstood what they mean or my knowledge is out-of-date. Thank you.

Comment: I should clarify now that, after working with this for a minute, `"moduleResolution": "Node"` was needed to use the `index.ts` file. That was the root of the issue.